# Хранить уникальные пары

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных

Хочу хранить массив из уникальных элементов, то есть например есть массив `[[1,2],[2,3]]`. Добавляю элемент `[2,1]`. Итоговый массив остаётся прежним, т.к. `[1,2]` и `[2,1]` одинаковые

Answer (score 1):

Для хранения неповторяющихся данных берем обычное множество (например, `set` в Python или `HashSet` в Java). Для хранения пар создаем свой класс, и переопределяем для него равенство и получение хэша так, чтобы объекты и с одинаковым и с разным порядком элементов считались одинаковыми (для Python - методы `__hash__` и `__eq__`, для Java - `.hashCode()` и `.equals()`, в других языках что-то похожее тоже должно быть).

Реализация на Python:

```
class Pair:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def _comparing_key(self) -> tuple:
        # Сравивать объекты будем по их элементам отсортированным по хэшу
        if hash(self.x) < hash(self.y):
            return (self.x, self.y)
        else:
            return (self.y, self.x)

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self._comparing_key())

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return False
        else:
            return self._comparing_key() == other._comparing_key()
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.x!r}, {self.y!r})"


items = {Pair(1, 2), Pair(2, 3)}
print(items)
items.add(Pair(2, 1))
print(items)
```

Вывод:

```
{Pair(2, 3), Pair(1, 2)}
{Pair(2, 3), Pair(1, 2)}
```

Comment: Вы изобрели `frozenset`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy нет, во frozenset не может быть двух одинаковых элементов, а тут Pair(1, 1) вполне может существовать.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $ python
> Python 3.10.0 (default, Oct 16 2021, 12:17:56) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> @>>> s = set()
> @>>> s.add(frozenset([1, 2]))
> @>>> s.add(frozenset([2, 3]))
> @>>> s
> {frozenset({2, 3}), frozenset({1, 2})}
> @>>> s.add(frozenset([2, 1]))
> @>>> s
> {frozenset({2, 3}), frozenset({1, 2})}
> ```

Если в списках могут быть одинаковые элементы, можно прибегнуть к конструкции `frozenset(Counter(lst).items())`:

> ```
> @>>> from collections import Counter
> @>>> s = set()
> @>>> s.add(frozenset(Counter([1, 2]).items()))
> @>>> s.add(frozenset(Counter([2, 3]).items()))
> @>>> s
> {frozenset({(1, 1), (2, 1)}), frozenset({(3, 1), (2, 1)})}
> @>>> s.add(frozenset(Counter([2, 1]).items()))
> @>>> s
> {frozenset({(1, 1), (2, 1)}), frozenset({(3, 1), (2, 1)})}
> @>>> s.add(frozenset(Counter([1, 1]).items()))
> @>>> s
> {frozenset({(1, 1), (2, 1)}), frozenset({(3, 1), (2, 1)}), frozenset({(1, 2)})}
> ```

Конструкция `tuple(sorted(lst))` тоже решает задачу:

> ```
> @>>> s = set()
> @>>> s.add(tuple(sorted([1, 2])))
> @>>> s.add(tuple(sorted([2, 3])))
> @>>> s
> {(2, 3), (1, 2)}
> @>>> s.add(tuple(sorted([2, 1])))
> @>>> s
> {(2, 3), (1, 2)}
> @>>> s.add(tuple(sorted([1, 1])))
> @>>> s
> {(2, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2)}
> ```

Comment: `frozenset([1, 1])` вашу систему сломает, два элемента превратятся в один.

Comment: @insolor, не сломает, а будет храниться как множество из одного элемента. Если это проблема, то `frozenset(Counter(lst).items())` её решит.

Comment: Ну, с Counter согласен. С "голым" frozenset - нет, пара не должна магически превращаться в объект с одним элементом.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо! Добавил второй вариант.